# Facebook Chat Hide my Flash Applicataion

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, actionscript-3, flash

I make a simple flash callbridge game. Everything is ok. But when I Opne Chat My flash is Hide from the canvas. Its happens for notification too. What can i do???

**When Chat is Down.**
[image]

**When Chat is open**
my flash is gone....
[image]

**When Chat is Down.**
my flash came back.
[image]

**When Notification is open**
My flash is also gone
[image]
you can check my app ==> https://apps.facebook.com/callbridze/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the reason of your problem here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/637/

so in the javascript init of facebook you have to add the `hideFlashCallback`:

```
FB.init({
    appId:appId,
    status:true,
    cookie:true,
    oauth:true,
    frictionlessRequests: true,
    hideFlashCallback : displayFlash
});
```

and in `displayFlash` function you can do what you want

```
function displayFlash( a )
{
    if( a.state == 'opened' )
    {
        // do what you want when a chat or notification is open
    }
    else
    {
        // do what you want when a chat or notification is closed
    }
}
```

Comment: but this process show only image. How can i play my flashgame and chat also notification at the same time or simultaneously. 
plzzz help me to solve this problem.... @binou brother.

Comment: if you don't hide your flash game div and don't put an image on it, the flash game is still on the place i think.

Comment: but user cant play that game. Even cant see the table. @Binou

Answer (score 0):

I have been having same problem a while ago. But there is a trick that you can use. If you set the following code to your object element, you see the problem will be solved.

```
#myObject {     
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```